# Some of the information required to submit your build for external testing is missing

Tags: flutter, app-store-connect

I distributed a Flutter app via Xcode to App Store Connect. But, I'm having some problems:

- Although the build is "Testing" and I added my account to "Internal Testing", I didn't receive the email to download the app. Also, I used to receive the build status in an email, and for this project I'm not receiving it.
- I'm getting the message, "Some of the information required to submit your build for external testing is missing." when trying to submit a build for review in "External testing"
- Even if I change the build version it stays 1.0.0, just the code changes.

Comment: I started having the same issue about 24 hours ago, and am seeing the same issue with multiple apps as well now. I made a new app using an Xcode template and got the same message and cannot submit any builds for review for external testing.
I was able to add one app's new build to an external test group, but that one I just changed the build number of an archived build and resigned it.

Comment: This seems to be some internal bug in Apple’s services. You’re likely better off reporting this as a bug to Apple.

Comment: Same here, did you solve it?

Comment: We see the same issue with our apps. No solution on Apple forums either: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/728389

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve the issue by doing the following:

1. Deleting the Testers from the external TestFlight group.
2. Add the build.
3. Add back the Testers.

If that doesn't work for you, I would suggest contacting [Apple Support](https://developer.apple.com/support/) (select "App Setup and Distribution", then "TestFlight" from the popup window).